# Help with combining objects

Tags: modeling, animation

So for this particular project, I need the object to be 1 but the animation to not move the actual machine. When I combine them together in the way I know how to it does this https://gyazo.com/fde11d1cecff66a43fb5b2d403f3a755

Comment: What is your question, could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I think you want to parent the smaller objects to the main objects.  This would be done by shift-selecting the smaller objects then finally selecting the larger object.  Finally, press <kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd> and select `Object`.  The objects with the red-orange outline will be parented to the object with the orange outline.  This means that their movement is now relative to their parent object.  You can find documentation of this behavior [here in the blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/parents.html).